# Set scroll area initially moved

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I need to create a big widget inside a scroll area and initially set both sliders in the middle of the bar. The scroll bar does not work, the widgets are not well connected I think.
MRE:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
import sys


class Diedrico(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
    # Draws stuff


class UiVentana(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UiVentana, self).__init__(parent)
        ventana.resize(1500, 1015)
        ventana.setFixedSize(1500, 1015)
        self.widget_central = QtWidgets.QWidget(ventana)

        scrol = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.widget_central)
        scrol.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scrol.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        scrol.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1010, 510, 470, 460))

        self.Diedrico = Diedrico(scrol)
        self.Diedrico.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000))
        # This widget should be big enough to use the scroll bar, but it does not work

        ventana.setCentralWidget(self.widget_central)
        ventana.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    ventana = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = UiVentana()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem comes from `scrol.setWidgetResizable(True)`, which seems to resize the content... setting this to False worked for me.

Also, to center the scrollbar, there are a few options, like setting the value of the [verticalScrollBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollbar.html) or using [ensureVisible(x, y)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#ensureVisible).

A working solution:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys

class UiVentana(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UiVentana, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()

        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 282, 331))
        self.label.setText("this is a long text\n" * 100)

        self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().setValue(300)

    def setupUi(self):
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)

        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 330, 301, 211))
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)

        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 282, 10000))

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = UiVentana()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```