# Initially moved scroll bar inside QGraphics

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I am trying to set the vertical and horizontal scroll bars initially moved inside a QGraphicsScene widget. The following code should move the bars and set them in the middle, but they are not moved:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys


class Diedrico(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.black), 5)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawRect(500, 500, 1000, 1000)


class UiVentana(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UiVentana, self).__init__(parent)

        self.resize(1000, 1000)
        self.setFixedSize(1000, 1000)

        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        # This two lines should move the scroll bar
        self.view.verticalScrollBar().setValue(500)
        self.view.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(500)
        self.diedrico = Diedrico()
        self.diedrico.setFixedSize(2000, 2000)

        self.scene.addWidget(self.diedrico)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_R:
            self.view.setTransform(QtGui.QTransform())

        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Plus:
            scale_tr = QtGui.QTransform()
            scale_tr.scale(1.5, 1.5)
            tr = self.view.transform() * scale_tr
            self.view.setTransform(tr)

        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Minus:
            scale_tr = QtGui.QTransform()
            scale_tr.scale(1.5, 1.5)
            scale_inverted, invertible = scale_tr.inverted()
            if invertible:
                tr = self.view.transform() * scale_inverted
                self.view.setTransform(tr)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = UiVentana()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I could move the bars when I used a scroll area such as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57706761/set-scroll-area-initially-moved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by @S.Nick works fine, but I'd like to add some insight about why you are facing this issue and what's happening "under the hood".

First of all, in your code you try to set the values of the scroll bars *before* adding any object to the scene.
At that point, you just created the view and the scene. The view widget has not been shown (so it doesn't "know" its actual size yet), and the scene is empty, meaning that the `sceneRect` is *null*, as in 0 width and 0 height: in this scenario, the scroll bars have a maximum value of 0, and setting any value won't give any result.

> NOTE: There is a **very** important aspect to keep in mind: unless
>   explicitly declared **or requested**, the `sceneRect` of a
>   QGraphicsScene is always *null* until a view shows it.   And by
>   "requested" I mean that even just calling `scene.sceneRect()` is
>   enough to ensure that the scene actually and finally "knows" its
>   extent.

After trying to set the scroll bars (with no results), you added the widget to the scene. The problem is that a view (which is a QAbstractScrollArea descendant) only updates its scrollbars as soon as it's actually mapped on the screen.
This is a complex "*path*" that starts from showing the main parent *window* (if any), which, according to its contents resizes itself and, again, resizes its contents if they require it, eventually based on their [nested widget] size policies. Only *then*, the view "decides" if scrollbars are needed, and eventually sets their maximum. And, only *then* you can actuall set a value for those scroll bars, and that's because *only then* the view "asks" the scene about its `sceneRect`.
This also (partially) explains why the view behaves in different way than a standard scroll area: widgets have a `sizeHint` that is used by the QWidget that contains them inside the scroll area, and, theoretically, their size is mapped as soon as they're created. **But**. this depends on their size hints and policies, so you cannot guarantee the actual scroll area contents size until it's finally mapped/shown; long story short: it "works", but not perfectly - at least not until everything has finally been shown.

### A test example

There are different ways to solve your problem, according to your needs and implementation.

- Set the sceneRect independently, even before adding any object to the scene (but if those objects boundaries go outside the scene, you'll face some inconsistency)
- Call `scene.sceneRect()` as explained above, *after* adding all objects
- Set the scoll bars only *after* the view has been shown and resized

I've prepared an example that shows the three situations explained above. It will create a new view and update its scrollbars at different points according to the checkboxes, to show how differently they behave. Note that when setting the sceneRect I used a rectangle smaller than the widget size to better display its behavior: you can see that the visual result of "Set scene rect" and "Check scene rect" is similar, but the scroll bar positions are different.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Diedrico(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.black), 5)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawRect(500, 500, 1000, 1000)

class TestView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, setRect=False, checkScene=False, showEventCheck=False):
        super(TestView, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(800, 800)
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.diedrico = Diedrico()
        self.diedrico.setFixedSize(2000, 2000)
        scene.addWidget(self.diedrico)
        if setRect:
            scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 1500, 1500)
        elif checkScene:
            scene.sceneRect()
        self.showEventCheck = showEventCheck
        if not showEventCheck:
            self.scroll()

    def scroll(self):
        self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(500)
        self.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(500)    

    def showEvent(self, event):
        super(TestView, self).showEvent(event)
        if not event.spontaneous() and self.showEventCheck:
            self.scroll()

class ViewTester(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setRectCheck = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Set scene rect')
        layout.addWidget(self.setRectCheck)

        self.checkSceneCheck = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Check scene rect')
        layout.addWidget(self.checkSceneCheck)

        self.showEventCheck = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Scroll when shown')
        layout.addWidget(self.showEventCheck)

        showViewButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Show view')
        layout.addWidget(showViewButton)
        showViewButton.clicked.connect(self.showView)
        self.view = None

    def showView(self):
        if self.view:
            self.view.close()
            self.view.deleteLater()
        self.view = TestView(
            setRect = self.setRectCheck.isChecked(), 
            checkScene = self.checkSceneCheck.isChecked(), 
            showEventCheck = self.showEventCheck.isChecked()
            )
        self.view.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    viewTester = ViewTester()
    viewTester.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Finally, remember that using absolute values for scrollbars is not a good idea. If you want to "center" the view, consider using [`centerOn`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#centerOn) (and its [item based overload](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#centerOn-2)), or set values based on `scrollBar.maximum()/2`.

Comment: Your answer is more precise and complete, also thank you for the last part, it is very useful

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the value when the widget is not yet formed, make it a moment.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Diedrico(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.black), 5)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawRect(500, 500, 1000, 1000) 


class UiVentana(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UiVentana, self).__init__(parent)

        self.resize(1000, 1000)
        self.setFixedSize(1000, 1000)

        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.view  = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.scene)

        # This two lines should move the scroll bar
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.set_Value)                   # +++

        self.diedrico = Diedrico()
        self.diedrico.setFixedSize(2000, 2000)

        self.scene.addWidget(self.diedrico)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

    def set_Value(self):                                              # +++
        self.view.verticalScrollBar().setValue(500)
        self.view.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(500)    

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_R:
            self.view.setTransform(QtGui.QTransform())

        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Plus:
            scale_tr = QtGui.QTransform()
            scale_tr.scale(1.5, 1.5)
            tr = self.view.transform() * scale_tr
            self.view.setTransform(tr)

        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Minus:
            scale_tr = QtGui.QTransform()
            scale_tr.scale(1.5, 1.5)
            scale_inverted, invertible = scale_tr.inverted()
            if invertible:
                tr = self.view.transform() * scale_inverted
                self.view.setTransform(tr)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = UiVentana()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why It has to be done in a different way when the scroll bars are at a graphics scene instead of inside a scroll area?